# struts 1 validation

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

Hi all I have a problem when working with struts validation as the following :
an edit profile page loaded , when user click save a validation should be executed if an error exist a redirect to the same page must happen with validation error showed, and data loaded, else execute method called. what happen that a errors list has values but no errors showed up in the screen, a snap of my code is :
I am using struts 1

```
<action path="/selectUserAction" validate="true" input="/selectUserAction.do"       type="com.bg.sharjah.usermanagement.manageusersgroups.web.actions.SelectUserAction" 
        name="editUserProfileFormBean" scope="request">


    @Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    //Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.WARNING,"");
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    try{

    errors = super.validate(mapping, request);
    System.out.println("validate <<<<<<<<<<< "+errors.size());

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return errors;
//  Validation.match(errors, password, confirmPassword);
    //Validation.match(errors, email, confirmEmail);    

}
```

Note:
my form bean is used with different actions, also I need to know how to redirect to the same page using input attribute ?

Comment: How are you displaying the errors?

Comment: Are you calling `validate` manually, or is the framework calling it?

Comment: If you're calling it manually you need to call `saveErrors`.

Comment: I just override the method does this mean I call it manually  ?

Comment: No, calling it means calling it.

Comment: by the way I sys out errors.size() it contains values, but nothing happen in the screen , does it related to scopes fpr example ?

Comment: No. There's not enough information to help; it should work fine if the request flow is happening the way you think it is. Any redirects?

Comment: <action path="/selectUserAction" validate="true" input="/selectUserAction.do"       type="com.bg.sharjah.usermanagement.manageusersgroups.web.actions.SelectUserAction" 
        name="editUserProfileFormBean" scope="request">, this way action not created so I can't acces the page it gives me an exception , but when I change input to other page it redirect to fail page but no error appears , plz tell me what information u need , or how can I find out that the flow works fine

Comment: Unreadable; if you have additional info to add, add it to the question. But simply stating an action definition alone isn't that helpful, you need to include what steps you're taking (URLs, data, etc.) to get to the page with the form, what it's submitting to, etc. It's a lot easier to provide all the information at once.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all I find out the problem it's a resource bundle issue.